# Particular solution:$ (3+x) e^{-2x}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$y''+4y'+4y = (3+x) e^{-2x}$

So I'm working with undetermined coefficient and figured out solution for the left side. But what is the particular solution for the right side? I tried these but they don't work as all terms cancel to zero:

$y = (Ax+B) x e^{-2x}$

$y = (Ax+B)e^{-2x}$

Comment: As you said, terms $xe^{-2}$ and $x^2e^{-2x}$ go to zero, so keep going. Use $(Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D)e^{-2x}$. This should work. You need that third power of $x$. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%2B4y%27%2B4y%3D%283%2Bx%29e%5E%28-2x%29) is a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $y_p=Ax^3e^{-2x}+Bx^2e^{-2x}$. Then solve to find $A$ and $B$. You will get the result.

Comment: thanks. could you please explain your choice?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: With $y(x)=(Ax^2+Bx+C)xe^{-2x}$, we have
$$
y''+4y'+4y=(2B+6Ax)e^{-2x}.
$$

Comment: thanks. could you please explain your choice?

Comment: @33ted You already tried $(Ax+B)xe^{-2x}$ so I just took the next natural step $(Ax^2+Bx+C)xe^{-2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the differential equation $$y''+4y'+4y =0$$ you surely showed that the characteristic equation has a double root corresponding to $-2$ and the solution would be $$y=c_1 e^{-2 x}+c_2 e^{-2 x} x$$

So, if I may suggest, reformulate the equation defining $$y= e^{-2x} z\quad ,\quad y'=e^{-2 x} \left(z'-2 z\right)\quad,\quad y''=e^{-2 x} \left(z''-4 z'+4 z\right)$$ Replacing, the original differential equation write $$z''e^{-2 x} =(3+x) e^{-2x}$$ that is to say $$z''=x+3$$ which explains the cubic polynomial to be taken into account.

You can easily concieve that for $$y''+4y'+4y =P_n(x)\,e^{-2x}$$ where $P_n(x)$ would be a polynomial of degree $n$, the same procedure would lead to $$z''=P_n(x)$$ and the solution would correspond to a polynomial of degree $n+2$.